# Query in Sparql to get data of a person

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to have a list of all mountains names of the *"dbo:firstAscentPerson"* property of Lionel Terray (dbpedia: http://dbpedia.org/page/Lionel_Terray).

[image]

This below is what I have so far

```
select ?person ?firstAscentPerson  where {
?person foaf:name "Lionel Terray"@en.
dbo:firstAscentPerson  rdfs:label ?firstAscentPerson.

} LIMIT 100
```

Comment: [Like this](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+%3Fmountain+%3FmountainName+%3Fperson+%3FpersonName+{%0D%0A++++VALUES+%3FpersonName+{%22Lionel+Terray%22%40en}%0D%0A++++%3Fmountain+dbo%3AfirstAscentPerson++%3Fperson+.%0D%0A++++%3Fmountain+rdfs%3Alabel+%3FmountainName+.%0D%0A++++%3Fperson+foaf%3Aname+%3FpersonName+.%0D%0A++++FILTER+(lang(%3FmountainName)+%3D+%22en%22)%0D%0A}+&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+).

Comment: Thank you a lot, really! I have understood what you have done!! I would never find by myself. Another question, in this your query, if I want to get, for example, for mountain, all the people that were the "dbo:firstAscentPerson" (like in the case of this mountain there are two, Lionel and another http://dbpedia.org/page/Fitz_Roy). Is possible to access data like this? Or I can just access the immediate data that is on  Lionel page?

Comment: `select * { dbr:Fitz_Roy dbo:firstAscentPerson ?person }`? Or do you want to get Terray's competitors "starting from" him? Well, combine triple patterns in some eay.

Comment: I would like to get not only from Fitz_Roy, but all the people that, together with Lionel, made the firstAscend to all montains that Lionel made his firstAscends

Comment: Then [this](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+%3Fmountain+%3FmountainName+%3Fperson2+%3Fperson2Name+%7B%0D%0A++++VALUES+%3Fperson1Name+%7B%22Lionel+Terray%22%40en%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A++++%3Fmountain+dbo%3AfirstAscentPerson+%3Fperson1%2C+%3Fperson2+.%0D%0A++++%3Fmountain+rdfs%3Alabel+%3FmountainName+.%0D%0A++++%3Fperson1+foaf%3Aname+%3Fperson1Name+.%0D%0A++++%3Fperson2+foaf%3Aname+%3Fperson2Name+.%0D%0A++++FILTER+%28lang%28%3FmountainName%29+%3D+%22en%22+%26%26+lang%28%3Fperson2Name%29+%3D+%27en%27%29%0D%0A%7D+&format=text%2Fhtml).

Comment: Amazing, thanks! But why for Fitz Roy there is no name of Guido_Magnone? In the property there are his name too: http://dbpedia.org/page/Fitz_Roy

Comment: [This](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fmountain+%3FmountainName+%3Fperson2+%3Fperson2Name+%7B%0D%0A++++VALUES+%3Fperson1Name+%7B%22Lionel+Terray%22%40en%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A++++%3Fmountain+dbo%3AfirstAscentPerson+%3Fperson1%2C+%3Fperson2+.%0D%0A++++%3Fmountain+rdfs%3Alabel+%3FmountainName+.%0D%0A++++%3Fperson1+foaf%3Aname+%3Fperson1Name+.%0D%0A++++FILTER+%28lang%28%3FmountainName%29+%3D+%22en%22%29%0D%0A++++OPTIONAL+%7B%3Fperson2+foaf%3Aname+%3Fperson2Name+.+FILTER+%28lang%28%3Fperson2Name%29+%3D+%27en%27%29%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D+&format=text%2Fhtml)

Comment: Thanks! Can you send the link to the code? This link is going directly to the results

Comment: Replace `query=` with `qtxt=`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin could you turn your comments into an answer please? That way it will be easier for other who stumble upon this question to see what the solution is.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra, the actual question was modified; it is not the initially posted one. That's one of the reasons I do not like to post answers :-). The closest answer to the original question is my first comment. As well as I understand, Catarina Nogueira was confused by these "is..of". Then, most likely, her question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The following query does what you need:

```
SELECT ?mountain ?mountainName ?person2 ?person2Name {
    VALUES ?person1Name {"Lionel Terray"@en}

    ?mountain dbo:firstAscentPerson ?person1, ?person2 .
    ?mountain rdfs:label ?mountainName .
    ?person1 foaf:name ?person1Name .
    FILTER (lang(?mountainName) = "en")
    OPTIONAL {?person2 foaf:name ?person2Name . FILTER (lang(?person2Name) = 'en')}

}
```